# Subclass SCNReferenceNode within SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

**Swift 5.5, iOS 15**

I want to subclass SCNReferenceNode, but having done so I get this error message? What am I doing wrong here? The code below compiles...

```
class CustomRNode: SCNReferenceNode {
    var tip:Tip!
    var x: Double!
    var y: Double!
    var tag: String!

    init(tip:Tip, x:Double!, y:Double!, tag:String, url: URL) {
        super.init(url: url)!
        self.tip = tip
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tag = tag
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

But when I try and use it ...

```
let gameURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "GameModel", withExtension: "scn")
let gameReferenceNode = CustomRNode(url: gameURL)
```

I get the error message?

```
// Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'.
```

Comment: Arent you calling `required init?` instead of `init` ??

Comment: Yes, your right I seem to be? But why?

Comment: Type `CustomRNode.init` and select the second one from the auto-suggest dropdown.

Comment: You seems to use the scnreferencenode initialiszr instead of customnode initialiser (missing tip,x,y parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide values for initialization parameters:

```
let refNode = CustomRNode(tip: tip, x: 0.12, y: 0.25, tag: "ref_01", url: url)
```

...or use a convenience initializer:

```
class CustomRNode: SCNReferenceNode {
    var tip: String!
    var x: Double!
    var y: Double!
    var tag: String!

    convenience init(tip:String!, x:Double!, y:Double!, tag:String, url:URL) {
        self.init(url: url)!
        self.tip = tip
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tag = tag
    }
}

let gameURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "GameModel", withExtension: "usdz")!
let refNode = CustomRNode(url: gameURL)

(refNode?.referenceURL)!                    // file:///<folder>/<folder>...
```